# Docker run command inside image

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a simple docker command to start conatiner:

`docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/bash image:v1.1`
I want to execute some command like `ls` inside the docker container. I can do it by use the command above to go inside the container and run it. However, I want a single command to run the command outside the container, like:

`docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/bash image:v1.1 --eval ls`

`docker exec` doesn't work in my case because the container isn't keep running in the background.

I don't know the exact syntax to add command to be executed into the docker run command. Can I get some help?Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
docker run --rm --entrypoint /bin/bash image:v1.1 -c ls
```

I've removed the `-it` options since you're no longer running the container interactively.

I've also added the `--rm` option to delete the container after it finishes. There's no need to have it laying around after it finishes.

You also need to add the `-c` option to your bash command, so the full command run in the container becomes `/bin/bash -c ls`.

Comment: Thanks! Actually, the command I want to execute also have -c. My command is:
 seeddb -c && listdb. Is there a way to escape my command to be something like:
docker run --rm --entrypoint /bin/bash image:v1.1 -c "seeddb -c && listdb"?

Comment: You can run multiple commands by enclosing them in single quotes, like this `docker run --rm --entrypoint /bin/bash image:v1.1 -c 'seeddb -c && listdb'`